# How to launch an Outlook template file?

Tags: outlook, autoit

How can I launch an "Outlook File Template" -file (.oft) using AutoIt?

I saved the .oft file to my downloads folder and want AutoIt to open it like as if double-clicking it in Windows Explorer. `FileOpen()` did not work; I want the .oft file to be opened in Microsoft Outlook in full screen.

Comment: [`ShellExecute("C:\Users\username\Downloads\filename.oft")`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ShellExecute.htm)

Comment: @user4157124 Perfect! That works. I tried to learn about the parameters like making sure it launches as full screen but I can't get that to work. But the solution is already awesome for me. :)

Answer (score -2):

> *I want the .oft file to be opened in Microsoft Outlook in full screen.*

As per [Documentation - Function Reference - `ShellExecute()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ShellExecute.htm):

> Runs an external program using the ShellExecute API.

Example:

```
#include <AutoItConstants.au3>

ShellExecute("C:\Users\username\Downloads\filename.oft", "", "", $SHEX_OPEN, @SW_MAXIMIZE)
```

Or simply `ShellExecute("C:\Users\username\Downloads\filename.oft")`.